# правильное создание элементов с помощью jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Пытаюсь создать несколько элементов с такой иерархией:

```
<div class="my-order-pr">
    <div class="my-order-pr-first-column">
        <img src="images/images/qqw1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="my-order-pr-second-column">
        <span class="h-for-product">product name</span><br>
        <span class="description-for-product">
           simple text
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="my-order-pr-third-column">
        <span class="delete">Удалить</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    $('.content-box').append('<div class="my-order-pr"></div>');
    $('.my-order-pr').append('<div class="my-order-pr-first-column"></div>');
    $('.my-order-pr').append('<div class="my-order-pr-second-column"></div>');
    $('.my-order-pr-second-column').append($('<span class="h-for-product"></span>').load( limkForProductPage + " #productName" ));
    $('.my-order-pr-second-column').append($('<span class="h-for-product"></span>').load( limkForProductPage + " #tabs-1" ));
}
```

но вместо ожидаемого результата в html выводится

```
<div class="my-order-pr">
    <div class="my-order-pr-first-column"></div>
    <div class="my-order-pr-second-column">
        <span class="h-for-product"><h2 class="for-zag" id="productName">Манометр, тип ХЗ</h2></span>
        <span class="h-for-product"></span>
        <span class="h-for-product"></span>
        <span class="h-for-product"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="my-order-pr-first-column"></div>
    <div class="my-order-pr-second-column">
        <span class="h-for-product"></span>
        <span class="h-for-product"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

и этот код повторяется в соответствии с количеством localStorage.length
Почему у меня не выводится нужная мне иерархия?

Comment: на так а зачем вы много раз одно и то же выводите, при чем тут вообще длина localStorage?

Comment: Длинна нужна для цикла, от неё зависит количество повторений

Comment: ну так допустим длина localstorage 4, тогда выборка `$('.my-order-pr-second-column').append($('<span class="h-for-product"></span>')` и добавляет 4 span. Поэтому `$('.my-order-pr').append('<div class="my-order-pr-first-column"></div>');` добавляет два раза `<div class="my-order-pr-first-column"></div>` если localStorage.length = 2

Comment: @Jean-Claude код который вы видите добавляется при localstorage равному 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема здесь с определением что и куда вставлять.
Селекторы класса, например `$('.my-order-pr')` выбирают **все** элементы на странице с этим классом. Поэтому результат при использовании этого селектора, как поиска только что созданного элемент, может быть неожиданным.

Можно разделить создание элементов на маленькие пункты, и тогда путаницы не будет.

Например, можно унести содержимое цикла в функцию, и использовать, например так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    $('.content-box').append(createOrder(limkForProductPage));
}
```

Сама функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
function createOrder(productPage){
    return $('<div></div>').addClass('my-order-pr')
                           .append(createFirstColumn())
                           .append(createSecondColumn(productPage))
                           .append(createThirdColumn());
}
```

Дальше по функциям создающим колонки

```
function createFirstColumn(){
    return $('<div></div>').addClass('my-order-pr-first-column')
                           .append($('<img/>').attr('src','images/images/qqw1.png')); // src возможно тоже надо передавать либо собирать
}

function createThirdColumn(){
    return $('<div></div>').addClass('my-order-pr-third-column')
                           .append($('<span></span>').addClass('delete')
                                                     .html('Удалить'));
}
```

И наконец второй столбец

```
function createSecondColumn(productPage){
    return $('<div></div>').addClass('my-order-pr-second-column')
                           .append(createProductHeader(productPage))
                           .append('<br>')
                           .append(createProductDescription(productPage));
}

function createProductHeader(productPage){
    return $('<span></span>').addClass('h-for-product')
                             .load(productPage + " #productName");
}

function createProductDescription(productPage){
    return $('<span></span>').addClass('description-for-product')
                             .load(productPage + " #tabs-1");
}
```

Comment: спасибо за такой развернутый ответ