# jQuery image source

Tags: html, jquery, атрибуты

Здравстуйте! Такой вопрос: например у меня есть динамический объект

```
var holderImage = "<img/>";
```

И у меня есть массив с атрибутами src

```
backgrounds = ["media/images/background/midkarBG_1.png",
 "media/images/background/midkarBG_2.png",
 "media/images/background/midkarBG_3.png",
 "media/images/background/midkarBG_4.png",
 "media/images/background/midkarBG_5.png"]
```

Я хочу им добавить атрибуты src, но так неверно. Подскажите как взять в качестве параметра атрибута src строку из массива по индексу? Заранее благодарен.

```
holderImage.attr("src", backgrounds[0]);
```

Подключил jQuery, чтобы не выдало ошибку.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [правильное создание элементов с помощью jquery](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513994/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с JS:

```
var holderImage = document.createElement('img');
backgrounds = ["media/images/background/midkarBG_1.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_2.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_3.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_4.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_5.png"
]
holderImage.setAttribute('src', backgrounds[0]);
```

Вариант JQuery:

```
var holderImage = $('<img>');
backgrounds = ["media/images/background/midkarBG_1.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_2.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_3.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_4.png",
  "media/images/background/midkarBG_5.png"
]
holderImage.attr('src', backgrounds[0]);
```

Проблема была в том, что `holderImage` был не элементом, а строкой. Что бы создавать элементу, нужно записывать их в `$()`.

Пример: `$('<a></a>')`, `$('<audio>')`, `$('<span></span>')`. При таких записях переменнтая будет равна элементу